# Git - submodule init/update - Complete newby

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

Today is my first day in GIT. I have been trying and searching for answers all day, but my unfamiliarity with GIT and the language has made it very difficult for me. Hopefully, one of you can help.

here are the instructions I've received at http://web.media.mit.edu/~mellis/cellphone/index.html

1. Checkout the cellphone's source code from GitHub, e.g. "git clone https://github.com/damellis/cellphone2.git".
2. Checkout the other repositories used by the cellphone's software with "git submodule init" and "git submodule update".
3. For the LED matrix variant, checkout the LED matrix branch with "git checkout led-matrix". (The code for the LCD variant is stored in the default master branch.)

I've been able to Checkout the source code per Step 1. Step 2 and 3 are not working for me, and I'm guessing there is more to the command than is written here.

Can you help me better understand the 'git submodule init' and 'git submodule update' commands for this project?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Checkout the other repositories used by the cellphone's software with "git submodule init" and "git submodule update".

That's presumably referring to the other GIT projects linked within libraries/. See the two Adafruit links here:
https://github.com/damellis/cellphone2/tree/master

> 1. For the LED matrix variant, checkout the LED matrix branch with "git checkout led-matrix". (The code for the LCD variant is stored in the default master branch.)

That's referring to the `led-matrix` branch of the project, seen here:
https://github.com/damellis/cellphone2/tree/led-matrix

I would recommend doing some research yourself or ask your professor directly if you don't understand branches or project submodules.